# Django Model Form doesn't seem to validate the BooleanField

Tags: python, django-models, django-views, django-validation

In my model the validation is not validating for the boolean field, only one time product_field need to be checked , if two time checked raise validation error.

```html
product_field = models.BooleanField(default=False)
       def clean(self):
            if (self.product_field is not None).count() < 1:
               raise ValidationError(
                    {
                       "product_field": _(" Product field can be select once")
                     }
                 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boolean and `None` are not always the same.  I think that is the root of your problem. Here is `None` vs `False`:

```
# python3
> False is None
False
```

I find the code and information confusing.

I assume `product_filed` is a typo. Generally `models.BooleanField` have to possibilities `True` and `False`. If `blank=True` and `required=False` are set then `None` can happen (unset aka NULL).

Keep the `default=False` and don't check for `None`, you should never see `None` with a default on a Bool.

You mention `if two time checked raise validation error` - Huh? This is also confusing. What are you trying to accomplish? The logic and details do not make complete sense to me.

To check the bool you can use  `if not self.product_field:` ... raise.

What is being counted?

Comment: Hi @Marc the product field was type error, and i am trying to accomplish if the product_field tick marked twice then the validation will rise.